# Deeper Reset than Factory?

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-s7, roaming

I have a Galaxy S7 which I purchased from Virgin Mobile a few years ago. Recently, because of international travel to Mexico and Canada I had it unlocked and now have an AT&T account. However, when I traveled to Mexico, the roaming feature is grayed out and it never connected to a network. The SIM worked, connected to the Mexican network, in another Android, so its not the SIM. As a last resort I factory reset. The Virgin Mobil splash screen came up, so apparently some settings are still in ROM. AT&T Tech Support verified a correct account configuration (roaming enabled)

*Is it possible to reset this portion of the ROM?*  I'm thinking the Intl Roam feature is disabled in the same manner that the splash screen wasn't blown away from a reset.

When I came back to the USA, the phone worked, but i had to manually set the data network access point.

Answer (score 2):

Virgin mobile is a proprietary prepaid Samsung Touchwiz Android repack - So that portion of the rom is not configurable.

What I would do is reflash the phone to North American Unlocked S7.

here's an XDA link with instructions.
it might be a bit of a pain but it will solve your problem utterly, and debloat your phone as well... making it a better phone quite frankly...

https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/help/sm-g930p-to-sm-g930u-t3813580